# Error: ‘AES_BLOCK_SIZE’ undeclared. Unable to compile OpenSSL with C in Linux

Tags: c, linux, openssl, shared-libraries

I have installed latest version of OpenSSL . I just try to compile and run the program [OpenSSL_aes](http://saju.net.in/code/misc/openssl_aes.c.txt).

While compiling with  gcc -Wall openssl_aes.c -lcrypto I got following error. I tried my best solve this problem , but unable to solve this compiler error.

```
openssl_aes.c: In function ‘aes_encrypt’:
openssl_aes.c:51:22: error: ‘AES_BLOCK_SIZE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   int c_len = *len + AES_BLOCK_SIZE, f_len = 0;
                      ^
openssl_aes.c:51:22: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
openssl_aes.c: In function ‘aes_decrypt’:
openssl_aes.c:75:45: error: ‘AES_BLOCK_SIZE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   unsigned char *plaintext = malloc(p_len + AES_BLOCK_SIZE);
                                             ^
```

**Edit :**

while I add `#include<openssl/aes.h>` as per @ martin, the compilation problem is solved.

now, gcc -Wall openssl_aes.c -lcrypto is successfully compiled.

But, when I try to run the program ( to run i used - ./a.out ), I got following error
**Segmentation fault (core dumped)**

Can anyone help me to solve this and run my program? I just want to perform simple aes encryption/decryption using OpenSSL. I am using GCC under Fedora 19 .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is AES_BLOCK_SIZE supposed to be defined in the library? If not, you should define it yourself (it should most likely be 16).

Comment: So, Can I add like #define AES_BLOCK_SIZE 128 ? I am using OpenSSL , is it ok to define ourselves ?

Comment: Which header file did you include? It may be the case that AES is not built or disabled on your OpenSSL compilation. Have you checked if `OPENSSL_NO_AES` is defined? Try this: `#ifdef OPENSSL_NO_AES #error AES not enabled #endif`. And no, it's not OK to define it yourself, this is the library's job.

Comment: @bholanath, while you *can* define it yourself, it's not a good idea. Also, it seems that it's defined as 16 in aes.h, as it's in bytes, not bits. See my answer below.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are probably not including `openssl/aes.h`, as `AES_BLOCK_SIZE` is defined in there as: `#define AES_BLOCK_SIZE 16`. So make sure you have:

```
#include <openssl/aes.h>
```

in your file.

Comment: Thanks @ martin . while I add this line, compilation problem is solved . But while tried to run, Core Dump error I am getting.

Comment: That's another issue for another question :) However, it's probably segfaulting due to bad pointer/array use somewhere?

Comment: @kedar, I think you have also tried the same example.